# draw border around CIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-image, ciimage

I'm looking for a way to add a solid border with Core Image. I have implement custom camera for taking pictures of rectangle shape documents. Now I am getting that documents four coordinates but problem to draw border on CIImage. Please help me.

```
 CIImage *overlay = [CIImage imageWithColor:[CIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0 alpha:0.6]];
overlay = [overlay imageByCroppingToRect:image.extent];
overlay = [overlay imageByApplyingFilter:@"CIPerspectiveTransformWithExtent" withInputParameters:@{@"inputExtent":[CIVector vectorWithCGRect:image.extent],@"inputTopLeft":[CIVector vectorWithCGPoint:topLeft],@"inputTopRight":[CIVector vectorWithCGPoint:topRight],@"inputBottomLeft":[CIVector vectorWithCGPoint:bottomLeft],@"inputBottomRight":[CIVector vectorWithCGPoint:bottomRight]}];

return [overlay imageByCompositingOverImage:image];
```

Comment: Its sound like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278647/add-solid-color-border-with-ciimage click on this link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this methods :

```
- (UIImage *)addBorderToImage:(UIImage *)image {
    CGImageRef bgimage = [image CGImage];
    float width = CGImageGetWidth(bgimage);
    float height = CGImageGetHeight(bgimage);

        // Create a temporary texture data buffer
    void *data = malloc(width * height * 4);

    // Draw image to buffer
    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(data,
                                                 width,
                                                 height,
                                                 8,
                                                 width * 4,
                                                 CGImageGetColorSpace(image.CGImage),
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, (CGFloat)width, (CGFloat)height), bgimage);

    //Set the stroke (pen) color
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);

    //Set the width of the pen mark
    CGFloat borderWidth = (float)width*0.05;
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, borderWidth);

    //Start at 0,0 and draw a square
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 0.0, 0.0);    
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, 0.0, height);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, width, height);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, width, 0.0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, 0.0, 0.0);

    //Draw it
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

        // write it to a new image
    CGImageRef cgimage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimage];
    CFRelease(cgimage);
    CGContextRelease(ctx);

        // auto-released
    return newImage;
}
```

Calling this method:

```
UIImage *updatedIMG = [self addBorderToImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithCIImage:overlay]]
```

Comment: It crashes on CFRelease(cgimage);